# How to create relative symlink powershell way?

Tags: powershell, file-io

It is not that simple to create ***relative*** symbolic links in powershell 5.1. `New-Item` is not working as expected. Some approaches are listed below. Am I missing something?

Sample setup for all examples:

```
mkdir C:\Temp\foo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
'sample contents' > C:\Temp\foo\foo.txt
cd C:\Temp
```

Sample1: Does **not** work as expected

```
#new ps5 Item cmdlets (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic) are not working well with relative paths
#C:\Temp\foo and C:\Temp\foo\foo.txt are returned
$fld = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name 'bar' -Target '.\foo'
$fl = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name 'bar.txt' -Target '.\foo\foo.txt'
$fld.Target
$fl.Target
```

Sample2: Does **not** work as expected

```
#Powershell community extensions
#same problem - paths are created as absolute: C:\Temp\foo C:\Temp\foo\foo.txt
$fld = New-Symlink 'c:\Temp\bar' '.\foo'
$fl = New-Symlink 'c:\Temp\bar.txt' '.\foo\foo.txt'
$fld.Target
$fl.Target
```

Sample3: Works as expected

```
#API call CreateSymbolicLink as per https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/new-symlink-60d2531e
#.\foo and .\foo\foo.txt are returned
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateSymbolicLinkW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);

    public static DirectoryInfo CreateSymbolicLinkToFolder(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName) {
        bool res = CreateSymbolicLink(lpSymlinkFileName, lpTargetFileName, 1);
        if (!res) { throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }
        return (new DirectoryInfo(lpSymlinkFileName));
    }

    public static FileInfo CreateSymbolicLinkToFile(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName) {
        bool res = CreateSymbolicLink(lpSymlinkFileName, lpTargetFileName, 0);
        if (!res) { throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }
        return (new FileInfo(lpSymlinkFileName));
    }
'@ -Name Win32 -NameSpace System -UsingNamespace System.ComponentModel, System.IO
[Win32]::CreateSymbolicLinkToFolder("c:\Temp\bar", ".\foo")
[Win32]::CreateSymbolicLinkToFile("c:\Temp\bar.txt", ".\foo\foo.txt")
```

Sample4: Works as expected

```
#using mklink from cmd produces correct relative paths
#.\foo and .\foo\foo.txt are returned
cmd /c mklink /d "c:\Temp\bar" ".\foo"
cmd /c mklink "c:\Temp\bar.txt" ".\foo\foo.txt"
(Get-Item "c:\Temp\bar").Target
(Get-Item "c:\Temp\bar.txt").Target
```

Edit: Sample3 has been updated to unicode api entry and GetLastError

Comment: PowerShell 6 [stopped resolving](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/commit/3a43126a2ea163f38c8d02c8177c79e954576ec6) New-Item's target to a full path for symlinks via globbing resolver. So until then you'll have to use workarounds.

Comment: @wOxxOm: thank you for information

Comment: @wOxxOm: Unfortunately, the commit you link to only added the ability to target non-existent items, without changing the behavior of resolving the specified path to an absolute path beforehand (even non-existent targets are converted to absolute paths). I've created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3500) to ask for relative targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with pwsh 7.1.X sample1 works as expected:

```
#new ps5 Item cmdlets (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic) are not working well with relative paths
#C:\Temp\foo and C:\Temp\foo\foo.txt are returned
$fld = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name 'bar' -Target '.\foo'
$fl = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name 'bar.txt' -Target '.\foo\foo.txt'
$fld.Target
$fl.Target
```

Comment: The leading .\ in the `-Target` path is important. It makes pwsh create a directory symlink (Mode `l----`). If you leave it out, it creates a broken file symlink (Mode `la---`).

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding this function to your $PROFILE.

```
Function SymbolicLink-Add 
{
[CmdLetBinding( )]
Param ( [string] $File, [string] $SymbolicLinkFolder )

$LinkFile = (Get-Item $File)

if ( $false -eq $LinkFile.Exists )
{
    return "Cannot create symbolic link file does not exist: [$File]"
}

if ( $false -eq ( Test-Path $SymbolicLinkFolder ) )
{
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $SymbolicLinkFolder 
    -ErrorAction Stop
}

New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $SymbolicLinkFolder -Name 
$LinkFile.Name -Value $LinkFile
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you would convert the target argument to System.IO.Fileinfo, then you would get the result you wanted, in the first version too.

```
   New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name "bar" -target ([System.IO.FileInfo]"./foo")
```

Comment: Does not work in PowerShell 5.1.19041.1682. This method applied to a RELATIVE path creates a link containing the ABSOLUTE path.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$fld = [string]"C:\Temp\bar"
$fl = [string]"C:\Temp\foo\foo.txt"

# Link to File
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target $fl -Path $fld  -Force

# Link to Directory
New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path C:\Temp\bar -Target C:\Temp\foo -Force
```

Comment: Beginning in PowerShell 7.1, you can now create to a SymbolicLink to a folder on Windows using a relative path.

Comment: This worked in PowerShell ISE (x86 tested version 5.1.17763.503) --> used this command to create a link called SteamGames: New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path SteamGames -Target SteamLibrary\steamapps\common -Force

Comment: FYI - If you don't know what version of PowerShell you are using, do this command: Get-Host | Select-Object Version

Comment: What is wrong with good old `$psversiontable`?

Comment: @MikeKennedy Indeed, it worked for me when using pwsh 7.1.2

Comment: Does not work in PowerShell 5.1.19041.1682. This method applied to a RELATIVE path creates a link containing the ABSOLUTE path. The example is not even a relative path as asked for in the question.